# Accessibility API: AXWebArea children elements (or HTML source)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit, accessibility-api

I need to get information from the third-party application using Cocoa Accessibility API. The third-party application uses WebView to show its user interface (`AXWebArea` role). This AXUIElement has no children.

```
 if ([role isEqualToString:@"AXWebArea"])
 {
        NSArray *names;
        AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(foundElement, (CFArrayRef *)&names);

        NSLog(@"%@", names);
 }
```

This code outputs:

```
AXRole,
AXSubrole,
AXRoleDescription,
AXChildren,
AXHelp,
AXParent,
AXPosition,
AXSize,
AXTitle,
AXDescription,
AXValue,
AXFocused,
AXEnabled,
AXWindow,
AXSelectedTextMarkerRange,
AXStartTextMarker,
AXEndTextMarker,
AXVisited,
AXLinkedUIElements,
AXSelected,
AXBlockQuoteLevel,
AXTopLevelUIElement,
AXLinkUIElements,
AXLoaded,
AXLayoutCount,
AXLoadingProgress,
AXURL
```

`AXChildren` is empty, so I cannot access HTML elements inside the `AXWebArea` UI element. How can I access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the web content is loaded?
I just did a little experiment with Safari.
With [this page][1] loaded, the Accessibility Inspector showed AXChildren with 83 items and AXLinkUIElements with 121 items.
But when I switched to a tab with about:blank loaded, it showed 0 items for both.

In my development environment the Accessibility Inspector app is at `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Accessibility\ Tools/`.

[1]: [Accessibility API: AXWebArea children elements (or HTML source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228459/accessibility-api-axwebarea-children-elements-or-html-source), i.e. this very page.